# How to make sequalize update to return the updated object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

With the update function, I'm currently getting the number of the affected rows. Is there any way I can get the key and values of that row instead of the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible in Postgres using the `options.returning: true` as documented in the [`update` API](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows).

> Update multiple instances that match the where options. The promise
>   returns an array with one or two elements. The first element is always
>   the number of affected rows, while the second element is the actual
>   affected rows (only supported in postgres with `options.returning` 
>   true.)

Together with the number of affected rows you are getting in the array, the second parameter is the affected rows you want.